# HighCharts wont load in Android webview on Android +4.x

Tags: android, highcharts, android-webview

I am having trouble getting HighCharts to render in an Android Webview. This is on Android 4.0+

Below is my html code

```
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="author" content="Script Tutorials" />
    <title>How to create active charts using Highcharts | Script Tutorials</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_1" class="chart"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {

// First chart initialization
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
 chart: {
    renderTo: 'chart_1',
    type: 'area',
    height: 350,
 },
 title: {
    text: 'Tools developers plans to use to make html5 games (in %)'
 },
 xAxis: {
    categories: ['Processing.js', 'Impact.js', 'Other', 'Ease.js', 'Box2D.js', 'WebGL', 'DOM', 'CSS', 'Canvas', 'Javascript']
 },
 yAxis: {
    title: {
       text: 'Interviewed'
    }
 },
 series: [{
    name: 'Dev #1',
    data: [5, 10, 20, 22, 25, 28, 30, 40, 80, 90]
 }, {
    name: 'Dev #2',
    data: [15, 15, 18, 40, 30, 25, 60, 60, 80, 70]
 }, {
    name: 'Dev #3',
    data: [1, 3, 6, 0, 50, 25, 50, 60, 30, 100]
 }]
});

});</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The I read the html file from the asset directory convert it into a string using a bufferedreader and then load it into the webview using

```
webview.loaddata(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Your customHtml keeps highcharts rendererd structure ? or page ?

Comment: Have you got any solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable Javascript in your webview? If not, just add this line in your onCreate method:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

where "webview" is:

```
WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i was working with highcharts and android webview...

```
WebView webview;
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.clearCache(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.loadUrl("your_website.com");
```

I used this code for the native app and it works very well...